# AuthorizationContext.Principal is changing from ClaimsPrincipal to GenericPrincipal automatically

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5, claims-based-identity

I dont know how come the context principle is changing in AuthorisationManager. My code is like

```
  public class AuthorisationManager : ClaimsAuthorizationManager
{
    public override bool CheckAccess(AuthorizationContext context)
    {
        var resource = context.Resource.First().Value;
        var action = context.Action.First().Value;
        return context.Principal.HasClaim(resource, action);
    }
    public override void LoadCustomConfiguration(System.Xml.XmlNodeList nodelist)
    {
        base.LoadCustomConfiguration(nodelist);
    }
}
```

I have list of items in GUI. It works fine first time but when I select second item the context.Principle is chnaged to GenericPrinciple.

Any idea will be helpfull on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK - WPF.

Yeah I vaguely remember that there is some "feature" in WPF around Thread.CurrentPrincipal.

try

```
Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetThreadPrincipal(principal);
```

IIRC you maybe have to do that in the App class (ctor?).

Comment: my application is WPF based desktop application and i am just loading the claims based on user into its ClaimsIdentity. Is it wrong, please correct me. How come it is defeating the purpose of claim based authorization..

Answer (score 1):

```
return context.Principal.HasClaim(resource, action);
```

Well - typically there is no 1:1 correlation of claims and authorization "decisions". Also in typical scenarios claims only hold identity data - something data can be used later to base authorization decisions on. The authorization manager then uses its own data management to make those decisions.

Now since this is a client application (I didn't know that it was WPF) you may do things a little differently. In server applications your approach would scale very well.